# DHCP Issue FOG Project Capturing Images

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, fog

I recently updated FOG from 1.4.4 to 1.5.0. When I go to capture a image off a host it gives this error:
https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/U0KLNaXqAMHQxsyMAsmlwyVtQpAzAglH/20180517_100332.jpg

It seems it is trying to start Eth0 network interface,

The FOG webui loads fine and DHCP is not giving any errors I just cannot capture any images.

Also as a side note we did add more storage and moved the images directory to another drive with a SIM link, not sure if that is realeted or not.

IF I got to deploy an image it does try to do Eth0 and fails and ask you to hit enter and it ends up deploying no problem. My issue is only with capturing.

Also if you trace DHCP when a machine connects via PXE boot it shows it by IP and says it does not accept TFTP options.

The status of my DHCP is: https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/J08p9FQbsYLXGwN5l8vqu3Z98q9LnLhP/image.png

My DHCP Conf File is:

https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/sqF0fk0cF5pcqG4a0ZesbQK5ooEeBAet/20180517_120927.jpg

https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/z8gfNItC5aXxVxn92EgdjkEX1BqVVQHX/20180517_120911.jpg

I just tried this on a switch that another FOG Server running the same version worked on. The FOG Server that I am having issues on still does not work on the known good switch. So it is not the switch.

Any idea on what the culprit could be in DHCP?

Comment: please copy-paste the content when possible instead of posting images

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by updating FOG from version 1.5.0 to 1.5.2.